# Do I need internet connection to install Spiderman for PS4 from physical copy?

Tags: marvels-spider-man

Is it necessary to have internet in order to install Spiderman from physical copy?

Comment: by "download spiderman" i assume you actually mean to install it from a physical copy right? because downloading would always require the internet

Comment: Yes installing from a physical copy does it need internet connection?

Answer (score 2):

No. Installation does not require internet access. Updates and DLC do.

To clarify, the PS3 and PS4 systems adopted an "installation" mechanic to allow the game to load faster and perform on a more optimal level, and reduce stress on the disc. This is a base feature of the system, and does not require any internet connection to complete. The disc has a complete version of the game, and does not require anything else in order to play.

If you do decide to play the DLC, you will need to connect to the internet in order to access it, but this is separate from the [vanilla game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanilla_software).

Comment: Can I play spiderman ps4 without doing any update or without installing the DLC

Comment: Yes. The game does not require updates or the DLC to be played

Comment: Are you sure? As I am buying the game next week I only have limited internet connection

Comment: Yes. I am done this many times before

Comment: Does it require psn access?

Comment: Installing a game on your PS4 is part of how the system works, to increase performance and reduce load times. PSN is an optional service that allows you to play online, or purchase additional content. You have purchased the disc, so you don't need to pay for anything extra to play.